# How do I get the domain name of a user from a machine not joined to the domain?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I am using `SystemDirectorySevices` to get user information from on-prem active directory from a machine not joined to the domain. The following code to get the user's domain name was working from a domain-joined machine, but not from a non-domain-joined machine.

```
public static string GetDomainName(this SecurityIdentifier sid)
{
    string? ntAccount = sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();    
    return ntAccount.Split('\\')[0];
}
```

I need the domain name, as in `MyDomain\myuser`, but I assume the above method depends on a relationship with the domain controller. What are my options in this scenario? Thanks.

**Update:** Thanks to answers below, this is what worked for me:

```
var user = new DirectoryEntry($"GC://my.company.com:636/<SID={sid}>", "username", "password", AuthenticationTypes.Encryption);
```

The above gives me a "A referral was returned from the server" result. I inspect `ref 1` in the `ExtendedErrorMessage` property to get the correct server. Then I query the correct server as shown below.

```
var user = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://other.my.company.com/<SID={sid}>", "username", "password", AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind);
```

Notice a few things I had to change between the calls in my case:

1. GC protocol to LDAP
2. Removed port number
3. Changed AuthenticationType to ServerBind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but only if:

1. You know the DNS name of the domain that it's on,
2. You have network connectivity to it, and
3. You have credentials you can use to authenticate to the domain.

```
public static string GetDomainName(this SecurityIdentifier sid)
{
    var user = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://example.com/<SID={sid}>", "username", "password");
    user.RefreshCache(new [] {"msDs-PrincipalName"});
    return ((string)user.Properties["msDs-PrincipalName"].Value).Split('\\')[0];
}
```

Replace `example.com` with the DNS name of your domain, and `username` and `password` with your credentials.

I understand that it's possible that if you don't know the short name of the domain, you don't know the DNS name either, which will present a challenge. If that's the case, do you at least know the AD forest that the domain is in (if it's a multi-domain forest)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, this works when running on a machine joined to the domain, but the same code on the non-domain machine throws an exception of `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007202B): A referral was returned from the server.` I'm not sure what I'm missing. Btw, I had to specify `AuthenticationTypes.Encryption` in the `DirectoryEntry` constructor, also.

Comment: A referral means, "I don't have what you want, but I know who does." Look at the `ExtendedErrorMessage` of the exception. There's a line that starts with `ref 1:` that will tell you which server you should be connecting to. Use that server instead in your LDAP path.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have it working now! `ref: 1` gave me the server and I was able to connect. I've updated my question with some more details about what worked for me.